# How to get Information out of SimpleCursorAdapter to ContextMenu

Tags: android, database, contextmenu, simplecursoradapter

I'm pritty new to Android and I've got a little question.
I've got a Problem with my ContextMenu. I have filled my ListView with my database entries, now i wand if i longclick it, that the ContextMenu pops up and there i want to delete or to edit my databaseentries:
But I don't get how I can find out what entrie it is.

Here's my Code..

```
    package de.retowaelchli.filterit.stats;




    import de.retowaelchli.filterit.R;
    import de.retowaelchli.filterit.database.ADFilterDBAdapter;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.ContextMenu;
    import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

    public class CreatedADFilters extends ListActivity {

        //Variablen deklaration
        private ADFilterDBAdapter mDbHelper;

        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);

            //Kontext-Menu registrieren
            registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.layout.list_layout));

            //Hier wir die Datenbank aufgerufen
            mDbHelper = new ADFilterDBAdapter(this);
            mDbHelper.open();
            fillData();

        }

       private void fillData() {

            // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getAllADFilter();
            startManagingCursor(c);

            String[] from = new String[] { ADFilterDBAdapter.NAME, ADFilterDBAdapter.ROW_ID };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };

            // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
           SimpleCursorAdapter adname =
              new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, c, from, to);
           setListAdapter(adname);

           mDbHelper.close();
       }


       //ContextMenu erstellen und definieren
      public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
           if (v.getId() == R.layout.list_layout) {
               getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.createdadmenu, menu);
           }
           super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
       }

       public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

           final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = 
                   (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

           switch (item.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.delete_adfilter: {
                   deleteAD();
                   return true;
               }
               case R.id.edit_adfilter:{
                   editAD();
                   return true;
           }
           return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
       }
      }

// THIS IS THE PART I DONT KNOW HOW TO REALIZE
       private void deleteAD(){
       }

       private void editAD(){
       }
    }
```

Thx for you Help in Advance!

best regards

safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `info` local variable in `onContextItemSelected()` has an `id` data member which contains the `_ID` value from your `Cursor`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants) demonstrating how to use that to delete an item based on a `ListView` context menu.

Comment: Thx you, I'm following you now on Github nice Project Samples! THX for your help!